# Use PHP to split an image into pixel divs

Tags: php, javascript, canvas, gd

This is tricky to explain, but for curiosities sake, I'd like to grab an image with PHP, split it into 1 pixel parts and do a foreach and assign each pixel to a div as an image/background image. So when the picture is displayed on the screen it looks whole, but its actually lots of 1px divs.

Using GD or a similar library, is this possible?

(Also, if this is easier with Javascript and Canvas then i'd be interested to know)

Comment: It would be interesting so see the results, could you post a link here?

Comment: @NCode working examples for both PHP/GD and JS/Canvas in my answer if you're interested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, you'd need to use the [imagecolorat](http://www.php.net/imagecolorat) function to select the image at each pixel, then loop through and render the elements as necessary.

Just because I found this interesting more so than practical I had a play around with it.

Below is some quickly thrown together code which demonstrates a couple of outputs from this. image.jpg is a 50x39px image of a monkey which amounts to 1950 1x1px images. The image below shows the output- the first image is the original, the second is the one with a matrix of 1x1px images as div backgrounds, the third is the hex colour picked from the original then `background:#xxxxxx;` on that 1x1px div. Be warned, **if you test this use a small image!** as obviously it generates an image for each pixel in the original image.

For future readers, this is more a proof of concept and should *not* be used in a production environment!

**Edit:** The third image in the screenshot obviously isn't rendered correctly- however this now works thanks to a suggestion by minitech. The code below has been amended to reflect this change.

[image: Original, 1px rendered, 1px hex colour rendered]

```
<?php

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
$w = imagesx($im);
$h = imagesy($im);

?>

<div style="background:url(image.jpg);float:left;width:50px;height:39px;"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
-------<br />
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<?php

/*
 * Do it with image creation, image per pixel
 */

for( $i = 0; $i < $w; $i++ ) {
    for( $j = 0; $j < $h; $j++ ) {      
        if( !file_exists( "dots/{$i}_{$j}.jpg" ) ) {
            $dot = imagecreatetruecolor(1, 1);
            imagefill($dot, 0, 0, imagecolorat($im, $i, $j));
            imagejpeg($dot, "dots/{$i}_{$j}.jpg", 100); 
            imagedestroy($dot);
        }

        $dots[$j][$i] = "dots/{$i}_{$j}.jpg";
    }
}

foreach( $dots as $column ) {
    foreach( $column as $row ) {
        echo '<div style="background:url('.$row.');float:left;width:1px;height:1px;"></div>';
    }
    echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
}

/*
 * Do it with picking the hex colour
 */

?>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
-------<br />
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<?php

for( $i = 0; $i < $w; $i++ ) {
    for( $j = 0; $j < $h; $j++ ) {
        $array[$j][$i] = get_hex(imagecolorat($im, $i, $j));
    }
}

foreach( $array as $column ) {
    foreach( $column as $row ) {
        echo '<div style="background:'.$row.';float:left;width:1px;height:1px;"></div>';
    }
    echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
}

function get_hex( $dec ) {
    $r = ($dec >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($dec >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $dec & 0xFF;

    return '#' . pad_hex( dechex( $r ) ) . pad_hex( dechex( $g ) ) . pad_hex( dechex( $b ) ) ;
}

function pad_hex( $val ) {  
    return strlen( $val ) == 1 ? str_pad(dechex( $val ), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) : $val;
}

?>
```

Just had a bit more of a play around with it and here's the same achieved with canvas and jQuery. It could easily be done without jQuery though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

        var image = new Image();  
        image.src = "image.jpg";  
        $(image).load(function() {  
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

            var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 39);  
            var pixels = imageData.data;

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            $('canvas').remove();

            for (var i = 0, n = pixels.length; i < n; i += 4) {
                var r = pixels[i  ] // red
                var g = pixels[i+1] // green
                var b = pixels[i+2] // blue

                // i+3 is alpha (the fourth element)
                $('body').append('<div style="width:1px;background:rgb('+pixels[i  ]+','+g+','+b+');height:1px;float:left;"></div>');
                if( i % ( 4 * imageData.width ) == 0) {
                    //alert(i);
                    $('body').append('<div style="clear:both;"></div>');
                }
            }
        });
    });  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><canvas style="display:none;" id="myCanvas" width="350" height="250"></canvas></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason the last one doesn't work is because you're not padding the output of `dechex`.

Comment: Also now added in a javascript implementation

Answer (score 3):

Sure. All you need is GD's [`imagecolorat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php). The result is just going to be a really, really big file, making this impractical for almost everything beyond an experiment.

Comment: This is what I like to hear :)

Comment: The is no imagegetpixel function, your link directs to imageSetpixel

Comment: @NCode agh, that happens when you do two things at once. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was intrigued with your question so I had a go at making something that would create an image with html tags but the size was so huge it was unusable. I spent the rest of the day making it as small as possible by creating a dynamic stylesheet compressing any web safe hex colors into 3 character versions, adjusting the width of multiple consecutive pixels to span that number of columns and removing the border of an image and replacing it with css padding.

```
<?

echo number_format(create_cssi('myimage.png')/1024) .' kb';

function create_cssi($file,$link=false){
    set_time_limit(60);
    $a = get_array($file);
    arsort($a['p']);//sort the color counter high to low
    foreach($a['p'] as $col => $count){//create css pallete .cRGB or .cRRGGBB
        $css[] = '.c'.substr($col,1).'{background:'.$col.'}';
    }

    foreach($a['xy'] as $x => $xy){//create image pixels with css
        foreach($xy as $y => $color){
            if($color==$a['cb']['c']){//if the pixel is the same as the border color (top left pixel) then don't use a class
                $cssi[] = '<i></i>';
            }else{//otherwise apply the color class
                $cssi[] = '<i class=c'.substr($color,1).'></i>';
            }
        }
        $cssi[] = '<div class="cb"></div>';//new line: .cb{clear:both;}
    }

    //now it gets a bit more messy, I did this part after to further compress the html
    //this finds all of the consecutive empty tags (<i></i><i></i><i></i>) and replaced them with single tags of the same width:
    //<i></i><i></i><i></i>
    //<i class="s3"></i>

    $cssi = implode('',$cssi);
    $counters = array();
    preg_match_all('%(<i></i>)+%', $cssi, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    for ($matchi = 0; $matchi < count($result); $matchi++) {
        for ($backrefi = 0; $backrefi < count($result[$matchi]); $backrefi++) {
            $count = substr_count($result[$matchi][0], '/');
            if($count>2){//3 or more consecutive tags
                $counters[$result[$matchi][0]] = substr_count($result[$matchi][0], '/');
            }
        }
    }
    $counters = array_unique($counters);
    $keys = array_map('strlen', array_keys($counters));//sort counters by key length ensuring the longest is first
    array_multisort($keys, SORT_DESC, $counters);
    $find = array();
    $replace = array();
    foreach($counters as $i => $c){
        $css[] = '.s'.$c.'{width:'.$c.'px}';//create a css class for the width
        $find[] = $i;                           //e.g. <i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
        $replace[] = '<i class="s'.$c.'"></i>'; //e.g. <i class="s6"></i>
    }
    $cssi = str_replace($find,$replace,$cssi);//do the highly inefficient find and replace!


    //still with me?
    //OK, now for all of the other colors - essentially the same thing but we're also saving the color in the counter array

    foreach($a['p'] as $span_color => $ct){
        $counters = array();
        if($ct>10){
            preg_match_all('%(<i class=c'.substr($span_color,1).'></i>)+%', $cssi, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
            for ($matchi = 0; $matchi < count($result); $matchi++) {
                for ($backrefi = 0; $backrefi < count($result[$matchi]); $backrefi++) {
                    $count = substr_count($result[$matchi][0], '/');
                    if($count>2){
                        $counters[$result[$matchi][0]] = array(substr_count($result[$matchi][0], '/'),'c'.substr($span_color,1));
                    }
                }
            }

            $keys = array_map('strlen', array_keys($counters));
            array_multisort($keys, SORT_DESC, $counters);

            $find = array();
            $replace = array();
            foreach($counters as $i => $c){
                $css[] = '.s'.$c[0].'{width:'.$c[0].'px}';
                $find[] = $i;
                $replace[] = '<i class="s'.$c[0].' '.$c[1].'"></i>';//$c[0] is the span width and $c[1] is the color class
            }

            $cssi = str_replace($find,$replace,$cssi);
        }
    }
    $css = array_unique($css);//strip out any diplicated css
    $style = '<style>.cb{clear:both;}i{width:1px;height:1px;float:left;}'.implode('',$css).'</style>';//build the style tag

    if($link!==false){//do we want this image linked?
        $pic = '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$cssi.'</a>';
    }else{
        $pic = $cssi;
    }

    //combine css pallete, image divs and wrapper and use the border removal valued as padding
    $tofile = $style.'<div style="width:'.$a['w'].'px;height:'.$a['h'].'px; padding:'.$a['cb']['t'].'px '.$a['cb']['r'].'px '.$a['cb']['b'].'px '.$a['cb']['l'].'px;background:'.$a['cb']['c'].';">'.$pic.'</div>';

    echo $tofile;//output to screen
    file_put_contents('logo.htm',$tofile);//store in a file
    return(strlen($tofile));//return the file size

}

function get_array($path){
    $img = imagecreatefromfile($path);//create the image from the path or remote uri
    $cb['t'] = 0;
    $cb['b'] = 0;
    $cb['l'] = 0;
    $cb['r'] = 0;
    $cb['c'] = imagecolorat($img, 0, 0);//get the top left pixel color (used for removing borders

    for(; $cb['t'] < imagesy($img); ++$cb['t']) {
        for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
            if(imagecolorat($img, $x, $cb['t']) != $cb['c']) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    //find a pizel that is not the top left corner color on the bottom
    for(; $cb['b'] < imagesy($img); ++$cb['b']) {
        for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
            if(imagecolorat($img, $x, imagesy($img) - $cb['b']-1) != $cb['c']) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    //find a pizel that is not the top left corner color on the left
    for(; $cb['l'] < imagesx($img); ++$cb['l']) {
        for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
            if(imagecolorat($img, $cb['l'], $y) != $cb['c']) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    //find a pizel that is not the top left corner color on the right
    for(; $cb['r'] < imagesx($img); ++$cb['r']) {
        for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
            if(imagecolorat($img, imagesx($img) - $cb['r']-1, $y) != $cb['c']) {
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
    $r = ($cb['c'] >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($cb['c'] >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $cb['c'] & 0xFF;
    $cb['c'] = rgb2hex($r,$g,$b);//convert the top left pixel color to hex

    $newimg = imagecreatetruecolor(//create a new image the size of the none bordered image
        imagesx($img)-($cb['l']+$cb['r']),
        imagesy($img)-($cb['t']+$cb['b'])
    );

    imagecopy($newimg, $img, 0, 0, $cb['l'], $cb['t'], imagesx($newimg), imagesy($newimg));//copt the section of the image without the border to the new image

    $newimg = imagerotate($newimg, 270, 0);//don't ask, something drove me nots with my pixerl array so I just hacked it with a rotate and flip
    $newimg = ImageFlip($newimg);
    $imagew = imagesx($newimg);
    $imageh = imagesy($newimg);
    $xy = array();
    $p = array();

    for ($x = 0; $x <= $imagew-1; $x++) {//cycle through every pixel of the image to build and array $xy
        for ($y = 0;$y <= $imageh-1; $y++){
            $rgb = imagecolorat($newimg, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            $h = rgb2hex($r,$g,$b);
            $xy[$x][$y] = $h;
            @$p[$h]++;//count the occurences of each color
        }
    }
    return(array('xy'=>$xy,'p'=>$p,'w'=>$imageh,'h'=>$imagew,'cb'=>$cb));//return the pizel array ($xy), the color count ($p), the original height ($h), the original width ($w) and the crop box with color at the top left corner ($cb)
}

function rgb2hex($r,$g,$b) {
    $r = dechex($r);
    $g = dechex($g);
    $b = dechex($b);
    $rp = str_pad($r, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $gp = str_pad($g, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $bp = str_pad($b, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $rr = str_split($rp);
    $gg = str_split($gp);
    $bb = str_split($bp);
    if($rr[0]==$rr[1]&&$gg[0]==$gg[1]&&$bb[0]==$bb[1]){//compress web safe colors to 3 character equivalent
        return('#'.$rr[0].$gg[0].$bb[0]);
    }else{
        return('#'.$rp.$gp.$bp);
    }
}

function imagecreatefromfile($path){//my fave imagecreate function
    $info = @getimagesize($path);
    if(!$info){
        return false;
    }
    $functions = array(
        IMAGETYPE_GIF => 'imagecreatefromgif',
        IMAGETYPE_JPEG => 'imagecreatefromjpeg',
        IMAGETYPE_PNG => 'imagecreatefrompng',
        IMAGETYPE_WBMP => 'imagecreatefromwbmp',
        IMAGETYPE_XBM => 'imagecreatefromwxbm',
    );
    return $functions[$info[2]]($path);
}

function ImageFlip($img){//image flip because I'm not great at arrays.
    $width = imagesx($img);
    $height = imagesy($img);
    $src_x = 0;
    $src_y = 0;
    $src_width = $width;
    $src_height = $height;
    $src_x = $width -1;
    $src_width = -$width;
    $imgdest =  imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height );
    if(imagecopyresampled($imgdest, $img, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y , $width, $height, $src_width, $src_height)){
        return $imgdest;
    }
    return $img;
}

function pre($a){//just useful for outputting arrays in a <pre> tag, not used
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($a);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

[image: png input]

From a 300x300 pixel png 86kb it creates a 1.1mb html equivalent

[image: html output]

Far better results can be made with images containing only a few colors like the twitter logo which "only" comes out at 78kb

[image: twitter logo 300x300 pixels]

Here's the output of a 40x40 pixel twitter logo

```
<style>.cb{clear:both;}i{width:1px;height:1px;float:left;}.c00aced{background:#00aced}.cfff{background:#fff}.c00a7ec{background:#00a7ec}.c00abed{background:#00abed}.c00a8ec{background:#00a8ec}.c00a9ed{background:#00a9ed}.c00a6ec{background:#00a6ec}.c00aaed{background:#00aaed}.c00a8ed{background:#00a8ed}.cf8fdfe{background:#f8fdfe}.c00a9ec{background:#00a9ec}.cfeffff{background:#feffff}.cfdfeff{background:#fdfeff}.cf4fbfe{background:#f4fbfe}.c02aced{background:#02aced}.c5cc9f2{background:#5cc9f2}.c09aeed{background:#09aeed}.cf6fcfe{background:#f6fcfe}.c6fcff4{background:#6fcff4}.c00aaec{background:#00aaec}.cebf8fd{background:#ebf8fd}.c04abed{background:#04abed}.c4ec5f2{background:#4ec5f2}.c07aeed{background:#07aeed}.c2bb8ef{background:#2bb8ef}.c63cbf3{background:#63cbf3}.c03aced{background:#03aced}.c11b1ee{background:#11b1ee}.c33bcf0{background:#33bcf0}.cc1ebfb{background:#c1ebfb}.cb1e5f9{background:#b1e5f9}.c04abec{background:#04abec}.cd8f2fc{background:#d8f2fc}.cd0effb{background:#d0effb}.ce1f5fc{background:#e1f5fc}.cf5fcfe{background:#f5fcfe}.ce2f5fc{background:#e2f5fc}.ccfeffb{background:#cfeffb}.c18b1ed{background:#18b1ed}.c3ebfef{background:#3ebfef}.ce3f5fc{background:#e3f5fc}.c20b4ee{background:#20b4ee}.c03abec{background:#03abec}.c42c0f1{background:#42c0f1}.c0bafed{background:#0bafed}.cb0e5f9{background:#b0e5f9}.ce8f7fd{background:#e8f7fd}.cfafdfe{background:#fafdfe}.c05adec{background:#05adec}.c30baf0{background:#30baf0}.c04aced{background:#04aced}.c45c2f0{background:#45c2f0}.cade4f9{background:#ade4f9}.cd4f0fb{background:#d4f0fb}.c85d6f4{background:#85d6f4}.c7fd4f5{background:#7fd4f5}.c6ecff4{background:#6ecff4}.ca7e2f8{background:#a7e2f8}.c46c1f1{background:#46c1f1}.ccdeefa{background:#cdeefa}.c54c6f1{background:#54c6f1}.c7cd3f4{background:#7cd3f4}.c8cd8f5{background:#8cd8f5}.c42c1f0{background:#42c1f0}.cb9e7f8{background:#b9e7f8}.cd1effb{background:#d1effb}.c62cbf3{background:#62cbf3}.cdff4fc{background:#dff4fc}.c5dc9f3{background:#5dc9f3}.cc3ebfa{background:#c3ebfa}.cd2f0fc{background:#d2f0fc}.c8dd9f6{background:#8dd9f6}.c13b1ee{background:#13b1ee}.c3dbef1{background:#3dbef1}.c4ec4f2{background:#4ec4f2}.ccceefb{background:#cceefb}.c9ddef7{background:#9ddef7}.c4dc4f2{background:#4dc4f2}.c22b6ef{background:#22b6ef}.ce0f4fc{background:#e0f4fc}.cc3ebfb{background:#c3ebfb}.cc8edfb{background:#c8edfb}.cd7f2fc{background:#d7f2fc}.cf7fcfe{background:#f7fcfe}.ce6f7fd{background:#e6f7fd}.c03aded{background:#03aded}.c13b2ee{background:#13b2ee}.ca8e2f8{background:#a8e2f8}.c00a4eb{background:#00a4eb}.c00a2eb{background:#00a2eb}.c0dafee{background:#0dafee}.c3dbef0{background:#3dbef0}.cdef4fc{background:#def4fc}.ccaecf9{background:#caecf9}.c64cbf3{background:#64cbf3}.cbee9fa{background:#bee9fa}.c6bcef4{background:#6bcef4}.c0baeed{background:#0baeed}.c1fb4ee{background:#1fb4ee}.c98ddf7{background:#98ddf7}.ca2e1f8{background:#a2e1f8}.cf9fdfe{background:#f9fdfe}.cecf9fd{background:#ecf9fd}.c8fdaf6{background:#8fdaf6}.c1ab2ee{background:#1ab2ee}.c7ad3f5{background:#7ad3f5}.c07aced{background:#07aced}.c96ddf7{background:#96ddf7}.c7dd4f5{background:#7dd4f5}.c20b6ef{background:#20b6ef}.cdcf3fc{background:#dcf3fc}.c77d1f3{background:#77d1f3}.ce8f7fc{background:#e8f7fc}.c1db4ee{background:#1db4ee}.c0fafed{background:#0fafed}.cd9f2fb{background:#d9f2fb}.c00a4ec{background:#00a4ec}.c35bdf0{background:#35bdf0}.c77d3f5{background:#77d3f5}.c2fbbf0{background:#2fbbf0}.c23b6ee{background:#23b6ee}.ce7f7fd{background:#e7f7fd}.c0db0ee{background:#0db0ee}.c5fcaf2{background:#5fcaf2}.cb5e5f7{background:#b5e5f7}.cd1f0fb{background:#d1f0fb}.cbce9fa{background:#bce9fa}.ca5e1f8{background:#a5e1f8}.c47c2f1{background:#47c2f1}.c66ccf2{background:#66ccf2}.c1cb3ee{background:#1cb3ee}.c8ddaf6{background:#8ddaf6}.c16b1ee{background:#16b1ee}.cb0e4f9{background:#b0e4f9}.cfbfeff{background:#fbfeff}.ce9f7fd{background:#e9f7fd}.c3fc0f1{background:#3fc0f1}.c37bef1{background:#37bef1}.cbce8fa{background:#bce8fa}.c6acdf4{background:#6acdf4}.c41c0f1{background:#41c0f1}.cf3fbfd{background:#f3fbfd}.c47c1f1{background:#47c1f1}.c87d7f5{background:#87d7f5}.c3fbeef{background:#3fbeef}.cc8edfa{background:#c8edfa}.ca2dff6{background:#a2dff6}.c4ac2f1{background:#4ac2f1}.c37bcf0{background:#37bcf0}.cc6ecfa{background:#c6ecfa}.cc1eafa{background:#c1eafa}.c01aced{background:#01aced}.cc7ecfa{background:#c7ecfa}.c7ed4f5{background:#7ed4f5}.c46c2f1{background:#46c2f1}.c4cc5f2{background:#4cc5f2}.ce9f8fd{background:#e9f8fd}.cd1f0fc{background:#d1f0fc}.c3bbef1{background:#3bbef1}.c78d2f5{background:#78d2f5}.cace4f9{background:#ace4f9}.cb1e4f9{background:#b1e4f9}.cf2fbfe{background:#f2fbfe}.c85d6f6{background:#85d6f6}.cf3fbfe{background:#f3fbfe}.c18b4ee{background:#18b4ee}.c0fb0ee{background:#0fb0ee}.c51c6f2{background:#51c6f2}.c5dcaf3{background:#5dcaf3}.c63ccf3{background:#63ccf3}.c26b7ef{background:#26b7ef}.c02aaec{background:#02aaec}.ccaedfa{background:#caedfa}.cdaf3fc{background:#daf3fc}.c05aded{background:#05aded}.c08aced{background:#08aced}.c62caf2{background:#62caf2}.c00a3eb{background:#00a3eb}.c0aaeed{background:#0aaeed}.c16b3ee{background:#16b3ee}.c19b4ef{background:#19b4ef}.c82d5f5{background:#82d5f5}.ca0dff8{background:#a0dff8}.c71d0f4{background:#71d0f4}.c88d7f6{background:#88d7f6}.c40c0f1{background:#40c0f1}.c76d2f4{background:#76d2f4}.ca3e0f8{background:#a3e0f8}.c00a5ec{background:#00a5ec}.c1db5ef{background:#1db5ef}.c2cb8ef{background:#2cb8ef}.c5fcaf3{background:#5fcaf3}.s24{width:24px}.s23{width:23px}.s19{width:19px}.s18{width:18px}.s17{width:17px}.s16{width:16px}.s15{width:15px}.s14{width:14px}.s13{width:13px}.s12{width:12px}.s11{width:11px}.s10{width:10px}.s9{width:9px}.s8{width:8px}.s7{width:7px}.s6{width:6px}.s5{width:5px}.s4{width:4px}.s3{width:3px}.s29{width:29px}.s28{width:28px}.s27{width:27px}.s26{width:26px}.s22{width:22px}</style><div style="width:40px;height:33px; padding:3px 0px 4px 0px;background:#fff;"><i class="s24"></i><i class=cbce8fa></i><i class=c6acdf4></i><i class=c41c0f1></i><i class=c37bef1></i><i class=c3fc0f1></i><i class=c63cbf3></i><i class=cb0e4f9></i><i class=cfbfeff></i><i class="s6"></i><i class=ce9f7fd></i><i></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i></i><i class=cf4fbfe></i><i class=cf3fbfd></i><i class="s18"></i><i class=cd8f2fc></i><i class=c47c1f1></i><i class=c00a9ec></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class=c00a9ec></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c37bcf0></i><i class=cc6ecfa></i><i></i><i></i><i class=cfdfeff></i><i class=cc1eafa></i><i class=c4ac2f1></i><i class=ca2dff6></i><i></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i></i><i class=c87d7f5></i><i class=c3fbeef></i><i class=cf8fdfe></i><i class="s16"></i><i class=cc8edfa></i><i class=c16b1ee></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class="s7 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c09aeed></i><i class=c8ddaf6></i><i class=c77d3f5></i><i class=c2fbbf0></i><i class=c00a6ec></i><i class=c23b6ee></i><i class=cf6fcfe></i><i></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i class=cfeffff></i><i class=c35bdf0></i><i class=c00a4ec></i><i class=c4ec5f2></i><i class=cf8fdfe></i><i class="s14"></i><i class=ce8f7fc></i><i class=c1db4ee></i><i class=c00a8ed></i><i class="s9 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c0fafed></i><i class=cd9f2fb></i><i></i><i class=cf4fbfe></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i class=ce7f7fd></i><i class=c0db0ee></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c47c2f1></i><i class=cebf8fd></i><i class="s13"></i><i class=c66ccf2></i><i class=c00a6ec></i><i class="s12 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c1cb3ee></i><i class=ca5e1f8></i><i class=cbce9fa></i><i class=c5fcaf2></i><i class=cb5e5f7></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i class=cd1f0fb></i><i class=c01aced></i><i class=c00aced></i><i class=c00aced></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c2bb8ef></i><i class=cc7ecfa></i><i class="s11"></i><i class=ce2f5fc></i><i class=c0aaeed></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class="s12 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c16b3ee></i><i class=c19b4ef></i><i class=c00a3eb></i><i class=c62caf2></i><i class=cfdfeff></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i class=cdaf3fc></i><i class=c05aded></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00aced></i><i class=c00aced></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class=c08aced></i><i class=c82d5f5></i><i class=cf5fcfe></i><i class="s9"></i><i class=ca0dff8></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class="s14 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00a5ec></i><i class=c5cc9f2></i><i class=cfeffff></i><i></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i class=cf6fcfe></i><i class=c1db5ef></i><i class=c00aaed></i><i class="s3 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c2cb8ef></i><i class=ca3e0f8></i><i class=cf8fdfe></i><i class="s7"></i><i class=c76d2f4></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class="s14 c00aced"></i><i class=c04abed></i><i class=c71d0f4></i><i class=cfeffff></i><i></i><i></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i></i><i class=c5cc9f2></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class="s5 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c2bb8ef></i><i class=c88d7f6></i><i class=cd8f2fc></i><i class="s5"></i><i class=c6fcff4></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class="s13 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a9ec></i><i class=c40c0f1></i><i class="s4"></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i></i><i class=ccaedfa></i><i class=c02aaec></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class="s6 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c07aeed></i><i class=c3bbef1></i><i class=c78d2f5></i><i class=cace4f9></i><i class=cd1f0fc></i><i class=ce9f8fd></i><i class=c7ed4f5></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class="s13 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c46c2f1></i><i class="s4"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s3"></i><i class=c77d1f3></i><i class=c00a6ec></i><i class="s8 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c00aced></i><i class=c11b1ee></i><i class=c11b1ee></i><i class="s14 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c4cc5f2></i><i class="s4"></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i class=ce1f5fc></i><i class=cb1e4f9></i><i class=cf2fbfe></i><i class=c5dcaf3></i><i class=c04abed></i><i class="s12 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class="s14 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c63ccf3></i><i class="s4"></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i class=cd0effb></i><i class=c00a9ec></i><i class=c26b7ef></i><i class=c51c6f2></i><i class=c0fb0ee></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class="s27 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c85d6f6></i><i class="s4"></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i class=cf3fbfe></i><i class=c18b4ee></i><i class=c00a8ed></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class="s29 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=cb1e5f9></i><i class="s4"></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i></i><i class=c5fcaf3></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class="s29 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c07aeed></i><i class=cdef4fc></i><i class="s4"></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i></i><i class=cd0effb></i><i class=c04abec></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class="s28 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class=c33bcf0></i><i class=cfeffff></i><i class="s4"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s3"></i><i class=c85d6f4></i><i class=c00a6ec></i><i class="s28 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c7fd4f5></i><i class="s5"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s4"></i><i class=c6ecff4></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class="s26 c00aced"></i><i class=c03aced></i><i class=cd4f0fb></i><i class="s5"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s5"></i><i class=cade4f9></i><i class=c30baf0></i><i class=c04aced></i><i class="s24 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ed></i><i class=c45c2f0></i><i class="s6"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s4"></i><i class=ce1f5fc></i><i class=cb1e5f9></i><i class=ca7e2f8></i><i class=c46c1f1></i><i class=c02aced></i><i class="s23 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=cb9e7f8></i><i class="s6"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s4"></i><i class=ce2f5fc></i><i class=c05adec></i><i class=c00a8ed></i><i class="s24 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ed></i><i class=c42c1f0></i><i class="s7"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s5"></i><i class=c8cd8f5></i><i class=c00a6ec></i><i class="s23 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c04abec></i><i class=ccdeefa></i><i class="s7"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s5"></i><i class=cfdfeff></i><i class=c54c6f1></i><i class=c00a6ec></i><i class="s22 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a6ec></i><i class=c7cd3f4></i><i class="s8"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s6"></i><i class=cf8fdfe></i><i class=c62cbf3></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class="s18 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ed></i><i class=c3ebfef></i><i class=cfafdfe></i><i class="s8"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s8"></i><i class=cb0e5f9></i><i class=c42c0f1></i><i class=c0bafed></i><i class=c02aced></i><i class="s16 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class=c20b4ee></i><i class=ce3f5fc></i><i class="s9"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s10"></i><i class=ce8f7fd></i><i class=c6fcff4></i><i class=c03abec></i><i class="s14 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class=c18b1ed></i><i class=cd1effb></i><i class="s10"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s9"></i><i class=cdcf3fc></i><i class=c6bcef4></i><i class=c0baeed></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class="s13 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c1fb4ee></i><i class=ccfeffb></i><i class="s11"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s6"></i><i class=cf5fcfe></i><i class=cbee9fa></i><i class=c64cbf3></i><i class=c0dafee></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class="s13 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c3dbef0></i><i class=cdff4fc></i><i class="s12"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class=ccaecf9></i><i class=c98ddf7></i><i class=ca2e1f8></i><i class=c96ddf7></i><i class=c7dd4f5></i><i class=c4ec5f2></i><i class=c20b6ef></i><i class=c00aaec></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class="s13 c00aced"></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c07aced></i><i class=c7ad3f5></i><i class=cf9fdfe></i><i class="s13"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class=cecf9fd></i><i class=c8fdaf6></i><i class=c1ab2ee></i><i class=c00a2eb></i><i class=c00a4eb></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00aaed></i><i class="s13 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00aaec></i><i class=c4ec4f2></i><i class=ccceefb></i><i class="s15"></i><div class="cb"></div><i></i><i></i><i class=cf4fbfe></i><i class=c9ddef7></i><i class=c3dbef1></i><i class=c03aced></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c00aaed></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class="s5 c00aced"></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c00a9ed></i><i class=c00a7ec></i><i class=c00a8ec></i><i class=c13b1ee></i><i class=c5dc9f3></i><i class=cc3ebfa></i><i class="s17"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s5"></i><i class=cd2f0fc></i><i class=c8dd9f6></i><i class=c4dc4f2></i><i class=c22b6ef></i><i class=c09aeed></i><i class=c00aced></i><i class=c00aaed></i><i class=c00aaed></i><i class=c00aaed></i><i class=c00abed></i><i class=c03aded></i><i class=c13b2ee></i><i class=c33bcf0></i><i class=c63cbf3></i><i class=ca8e2f8></i><i class=ce6f7fd></i><i class="s19"></i><div class="cb"></div><i class="s8"></i><i class=cf7fcfe></i><i class=ce0f4fc></i><i class=ccfeffb></i><i class=cc3ebfb></i><i class=cc1ebfb></i><i class=cc1ebfb></i><i class=cc8edfb></i><i class=cd7f2fc></i><i class=cebf8fd></i><i class="s23"></i><div class="cb"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jep, here's the function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php

But it would be very very VERY inefficent to do this, because instead of transfering one number per pixel you are transferring a string with the div, so don't expect a shorter loadingtime.